# Validation happens before view is loaded

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, unobtrusive-validation

Ok here's the deal. I have a simple log in screen (in a separate area), and when I select Log In in the menu the log in screen loads perfectly, but it shows the errors, like simply loading the view executes the validation (unobtrusive jQuery).

Here's the link for the Log In page:

```
<li> <%: Html.ActionLink("Log In", "Index", "Login", new { area = "AdminArea" }, null)%></li>
```

This is the Login View:

```
<%= Html.RenderScript("MicrosoftMvcJQueryValidation")%>
<%= Html.RenderScript("json2")%>
<%= Html.RenderScript("loginForm")%>
<%  Html.EnableClientValidation(); %>

<% using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Login", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "signin" }))
{
    ViewContext.FormContext.ValidationSummaryId = "valLoginContainer"; %>
<fieldset>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Password">&nbsp;</label>
    </span>
    <table style="width" border="none;">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <%= Html.JQueryValidationSummary("Please fix the following error(s):", new Dictionary<string, object> { { "id", "valLoginContainer" } })%>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<legend>Admin Login</legend>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Username">Username:</label>
    </span>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Username, new { @class = "inputbox" })%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Username, " *")%>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Password">Password:</label>
    </span>
    <%= Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.Password, new { @class = "inputbox" })%><%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, " *")%>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Password">&nbsp;</label>
    </span><a href="#" id="forgot_password_link" title="Click here to reset your password."> Forgot password?</a>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Password">&nbsp;</label>
    </span>
    <a href="#" id="forgot_username_link" title="Fogot your login name? We can help with that"> Forgot username?</a>
</div>
    <div class="row">
    <span class="label">
        <label for="Password">&nbsp;</label>
    </span>
    <input type="submit" id="action" value="Submit &raquo;" class="formButtons" />
</div>
</fieldset>
<%}%>
```

Anyone have any ideas why the validation is execute when the view loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue has been resolved. I was missing a JS file (that I was unaware of) and once I added the file everything works beautifully. Also, in LoginController.cs I had this line which was incorrect

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Once I changed it to this all was well'

```
public virtual ActionResult Index()
{
    return View(new LoginViewModel());
}
```

LoginViewModel looks like this:

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Username/email is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks to all who looked at it.